# Archunit - classes may only be used once

Tags: java, junit, archunit

i want to implement a rule which makes sure classes of type "Repository" are not being shared among classes of type "Service".
That means a Service can use as many Repositories as it wants, but a Repository must only be used by one Service (no sharing of Repositories). How would I achive that....?

What I have now is:

```
@ArchTest
static final ArchRule repository_must_only_be_used_by_a_service =
        classes().that().resideInAnyPackage(SUBPACKAGE_NAME_REPOSITORY).should().onlyHaveDependentClassesThat()
                    .resideInAnyPackage(SUBPACKAGE_NAME_SERVICE);

@ArchTest
static final ArchRule repository_must_only_be_used_by_one_service = ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a custom `ArchCondition` checking for dependent classes, which can be very concise:

```java
import static com.tngtech.archunit.base.DescribedPredicate.describe;
import static com.tngtech.archunit.lang.conditions.ArchConditions.have;
import static com.tngtech.archunit.lang.syntax.ArchRuleDefinition.classes;

// ...

@ArchTest
ArchRule repository_must_have_exactly_one_dependent_class =
    classes().that().resideInAnyPackage(SUBPACKAGE_NAME_REPOSITORY)
        .should(have(describe("#{dependent classes} == 1", javaClass ->
            javaClass.getDirectDependenciesToSelf().stream()
                .map(Dependency::getOriginClass).count() == 1
        )));
```

I'd probably implement the `ArchCondition` myself to get a more helpful violation message:

```java
import static com.tngtech.archunit.lang.ConditionEvent.createMessage;
import static com.tngtech.archunit.lang.SimpleConditionEvent.violated;
import static com.tngtech.archunit.lang.syntax.ArchRuleDefinition.classes;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toSet;

// ...

@ArchTest
ArchRule repository_must_have_exactly_one_dependent_class =
    classes().that().resideInAnyPackage(SUBPACKAGE_NAME_REPOSITORY)
        .should(new ArchCondition<JavaClass>("have one dependent class") {
            @Override
            public void check(JavaClass javaClass, ConditionEvents events) {
                Set<JavaClass> dependentClasses = 
                    javaClass.getDirectDependenciesToSelf().stream()
                        .map(Dependency::getOriginClass)
                        .collect(toSet());
                if (dependentClasses.size() != 1) {
                    String message = dependentClasses.isEmpty()
                        ? "has no dependent classes"
                        : dependentClasses.stream()
                            .map(JavaClass::getName)
                            .collect(joining(", ", "has several dependent classes: ", ""));
                    events.add(violated(javaClass, createMessage(javaClass, message)));
                }
            }
        });
```